# Having Trouble Finding a Faculty Member for Math Undergraduate Research

Tags: mathematics, professorship, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate pursuing mathematics and computer science in the research university at U.S.  Inspired from the applications of algebra to math and statistics, I have been trying to find a suitable project in the mathematics with supervision from a faculty member, or a reading course in some topics of the pure mathematics.  I have been sending emails to professors at the math department for either a reading course or a project (regardless of the difficulty) I can pursue, but they are either not interested or ignoring my emails and corresponding followup reminders.  When I visited one of faculties during her office hour, she told me that she have been ignoring my emails since she is not interested in my proposal of research idea (I felt sad for a while as I hope she just informed me she is not available).

The general outline is that I approach professors doing research similar to my interest, and ask them if they have any available project.  If they do not have projects, then I ask them if they are interested in hearing about my own ideas.

I am started to feel anxious about it as I really like to work with professors in the mathematics (my interests are not really in the domain of CS, but more or less the pure mathematics and its applications in theories of CS); I am interested in their research, but they are not interested. I understand the busy schedules of professors, so I am curious if there us any way to approach them to acquire the opportunities of project or reading course. So far, none of the professors at the department is interested or available...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54352/discussion-on-question-by-mathwanderer-having-trouble-finding-a-faculty-member-f).

Comment: Have you taken a class from these professors? If not, then they have no clear idea of whether you are capable of doing research in math.

Comment: @BenCrowell  Of course, I took some classes from the professors.  Unfortunately, they were either undergoing a medical treatment or leaving for sabbatical years, so I had to luck there.  That is why I am trying other professors.

Comment: @scaaahu Please read the chatting discussion.  I did read my previous posts.

Comment: In the linked question, you asked  "_should I request of doing independent reading under them and later proceed with the research? **How should I ask them?** What should I address?"_. Can you tell us why this is not a duplicate?

Comment: @scaaahu  Because I DID ask them in the past, which were followed by responses from the faculties to come back later after taking more courses.  I also tried the methods mentioned on the last post during my recent initial visits, but also rejected.  This is why I am asking again.  Also, they were discussed in the chat link above.  Now, please do not interfere with my effort to trying to get advices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest that you take a different approach, for now.

1. When you visit or email a researcher, start by reading some of his or her writing.  The start the conversation by speaking about the article you read.  Mention something you found interesting or well explained.  Ask a question about something you didn't understand.  If necessary ask for some recommended background papers.  Ask a question about future directions.  Then ask the researcher what s/he is working on currently.  Be a good listener.
2. Keep a notebook of project ideas.  Put your current project in this notebook.
3. Ask each professor you visit if s/he has any projects to offer for summer.  Listen carefully to the project description.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! My interests are in the complex analysis, differential geometry, and probability theory, and their applications to problems in the information geometry. I actually took both relevant undergraduate and graduate courses in those mathematical branches, so I think I am ready to at least begin to read the papers. This is why I am frustrated since I have a strong background in them.

Comment: When I was rejected for undergraduate search request, I actually did followup with a request of reading course; of course, I read some of their foundational and latests papers to deduce specific topics that could be interest to us both. I do not demand significant time, as I requested an hour or so for every week or two weeks, and they are still not interested.

Comment: Also, it seems none of the faculties are available during Summer as they have frequent traveling schedules...

Comment: I'm not sure if you want practical suggestions, or a misery-loves-company cluck-cluck sort of sympathetic listening.  It's starting to look like the latter.

Comment: Of course, I would prefer practical suggestions.  However, I tried all approaches, including yours.  I am looking for other ways; I tried all general approaches like yours, so that is why I wrote this post in the stack exchange.  Please do not make immature, childish suggestions.

Comment: @MathWanderer - Can you pinpoint which part of my answer or my comments struck you as immature or childish?  That was, of course, not my intention. // If you started some of your conversations with a sincere interest in *what the researcher is doing and finds exciting*, and if you showed a willingness to *postpone your proposed project, and accept a **different** project, proposed by the researcher*, please edit your question.

Comment: I meant the "misery-loves-company cluck-cluck...".  Of course, it might mean nothing to many people, but there are some people with different mental healths or cultures who could view it as mockery.  To me, that phrase seems very offensive and comes as immature.

Comment: @MathWanderer - Okay, I see, thanks for explaining.  "Cluck cluck" is similar to "tut tut."  It's an expression of sympathy. // Your edit is helpful. // I'm starting to run low on ideas for you since it sounds like you've already done a lot.  But here are two more. 1) Talk to some administrators. 2) Try writing to a couple of people whose articles interest you.

Comment: Alright.  Do you think it would be worth revisiting the professor who told me she ignored my emails (when I met with her during office hours) due to some differences in our interests?  I am also really interested in her research topics, and I have been reading some of her foundational papers.  I would like to convince her again, but I am not sure if that will be effective as she ignored me.

Comment: @MathWanderer - Well, there might not be much point in pushing someone flaky or unreliable to accept a commitment they might not live up to.  It wouldn't hurt to try, as long as you're not pushy. // I think it's time to look for some kind of mentor on the ground; it's okay if the person is not in your area.  This might be a temporary mentor.  Just look for someone with a helpful attitude.